# How to dispose of one JFrame when two are open and have the same name

Tags: java, jframe

Basically I have one JFrame which is opened twice but it needs to dispose of one of them and they both have the same name. There is a reason why one JFrame needs to be opened twice but the reason is very long and probably isn’t relevant but if you need to know why just ask.

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, it will be much easier for everyone to understand your problem and answer your question.

Comment: The only way to do that would be two files and a few hundred lines of code so I think no code is better